# Apache CXF cast exception on WSDL

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I have this public WSDL: http://ihexds.nist.gov:12080/tf6/services/xdsregistryb?wsdl

It's the WSDL for a public XDS Registry service and I want to make calls to it from my application.

When I run "wsdl2java" on it with Apache CXF 2.7.8 I get the following exception

```
WSIBP Validator found <{http://serviceclasses.ws.registry.nist.gov}xdsregistrybHttpBinding> is NOT a SOAP binding

WSDLToJava Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be cast to java.lang.String

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:420)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.annotator.WSActionAnnotator.getAction(WSActionAnnotator.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.annotator.WSActionAnnotator.annotate(WSActionAnnotator.java:83)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaMethod.annotate(JavaMethod.java:368)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.OperationProcessor.process(OperationProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.internal.PortTypeProcessor.process(PortTypeProcessor.java:149)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.WSDLToJavaProcessor.wsdlDefinitionToJavaModel(WSDLToJavaProcessor.java:82)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.WSDLToJavaProcessor.process(WSDLToJavaProcessor.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:285)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
... 4 more
```

Anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Try to validate the wsdl: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdlvalidator.html

Comment: The output of that is simply: `Passed Validation : Valid WSDL` even though one of the bindings isn't a SOAP binding.

Comment: Apparently, the problem only exists when calling the tool from Eclipse, if I run the program directly, it works.